# Create a list by selecting from another in F#

Tags: f#

I am new to F#, I have been going through first few chapters of F# for C# developers. I am stuck at this point and I need help. If anybody thinks I am going against the purpose of this website, please let me know I will remove my question.

I have the following list

```
let list1 = [0..100]
```

I want to create a list from the list above but select only the numbers that are divisible by 5. I am trying the following.

```
let list2 = [for i in list1 do yield if i%5=0 then i]
```

But the above is giving me compile error as follows. Why is that ? Why it could not simply infer the type int?

> Program.fs(6,52): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have
>   type
>       unit     but here has type
>       int

Answer (score 4):

You need to move the `yield` inside the `if`:

```
let list2 = [for i in list1 do if i%5=0 then yield i]
```

An `if ... then` expression with no `else` can only return something of type `unit`, because the whole expression has to have a value, and if the condition is not satisfied the compiler won't just make up a value of any other type.

In your case you were trying to say that the expression should produce an `int` if the condition was satisfied, and nothing otherwise; the proper way to do that is to make the `yield` conditional as well. Otherwise you are saying you always want to produce a value, even if the condition isn't satisfied.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to filter, it's easier to just use the built-in [filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370294.aspx) function:

```
let list2 = list1 |> List.filter (fun x -> x % 5 = 0)
```

Given your `list1`, it produces the output

> [0; 5; 10; 15; 20; 25; 30; 35; 40; 45; 50; 55; 60; 65; 70; 75; 80; 85; 90; 95; 100]

Comment: +1, the built-in list functions are very powerful and they cover everything.

Comment: [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh967652.aspx) could also be helpful. There is full list of F# collections functions and their descriptions.